# Remove jar during runtime on Sub-Module in Android Studio

Tags: android, jar, gradle, runtimeexception, amazon-device-messaging

i have three build.gradle files on for the project (project build.gradle) one for the main module (main build.gradle) and one for another sub-module (submodule build.gradle)

My submodule `build.gradle` uses ADM (Amazon Device Messaging). and therefore has the following dependency attached.

using the provided dependency on the main build.gradle works but it doesnt work if i add it to the submodule. The following works if on

**main build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', exclude: 'amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar', include: '*.jar')
    provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
}
```

**What I have tried**

1. Added the following to **submodule build.gradle** (still get runtime exception)

   ```
   configurations {
       provided
   }
   sourceSets {
   main {
       compileClasspath += configurations.provided
   }
   test {
       compileClasspath += configurations.provided
       }
   }

   sourceSets.main.compileClasspath += configurations.provided

   dependencies {
   provided files('libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar')
   }
   ```

NOTE : I have also changed provided to something custom like providedlibs and it still doesn't work

2. Added the following to the **submodule build.gradle** file (runtime exception still)

   ```
   android.libraryVariants.all { 
   variant -> variant.packageLibrary.exclude( 'ext_libs/amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar' )
   }
   ```
3. Added the following to **submodule build.gradle** file  (I cant even  compile with this fellah - i guess it removes during build as well)

   ```
   android.libraryVariants.all { variant ->
       variant.outputs.each { output ->
           output.packageLibrary.exclude('libs/someLib.jar')
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works is adding dependency to a maven repo and including it in the library with the provided dependency

Answer (score 0):

1. Add the ADM jar in the Maven local repository.

Command :

```
            mvn install:install-file "-Dfile=amazon-device-messaging-1.0.1.jar" "-DgroupId=com.amazon.device.messaging" "-DartifactId=amazondevicemessaging" "-Dversion=1.0.1" "-Dpackaging=jar"
```

2. Include local maven repository as project dependency :

Add “mavenLocal()” in main Gradle build script:

```
            allprojects {
            repositories {
                            mavenCentral()
                            mavenLocal()
             }
```

3. Link the Maven artifact in ADM project.

Add below line ADMWrapperLib Gradle script (::).

dependencies 
{
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

```
provided 'com.amazon.device.messaging:amazondevicemessaging:1.0.1'
```

}